# Unable to resolve the error “Unable to access jarfile ApacheJMeter.jar errorlevel=1” even after adding ApacheJMeter.jar file to bin folder

Tags: java, jmeter

I tried adding ApacheJMeter.jar to bin folder,after clicking on jmeter.bat file, the command prompt suddenly flashes and gets disappeared.Please somebody help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

option 1: Please download the latest stable build from apache site and use it

option 2: Please post additional details on the changes made

Comment: When I downloaded JMeter and tried running jmeter.bat file, it was showing an error message in the command prompt that “Unable to access jarfile ApacheJMeter.jar errorlevel=1”.So I downloaded ApacheJMeter.jar and put into bin folder.But when i tried running jmeter.bat file again then the command prompt was flashing some error message and suddenly the window is getting closed.

Comment: please re download complete build